# How to store a file in SQL Server databases using classic asp?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am trying to store a file in a SQL Server 2008 database. Since the size of file is small, performance is not an issue.

My table has this 3 columns:

```
filename nvarchar(50)
extension nvarchar(5)
content image
```

How to write a SQL statement to insert a file into this database?

Comment: First: I would **not** use `Image` - it's a **deprecated** datatype, use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead. Also: for a string of only 5 characters length, the at least 2 byte overhead for `nvarchar` is hardly worth it - I'd recommend using `nchar(5)` instead.

Comment: What have tried already and what specific problems did you have? Saving binary files in a database is a common, well-documented task, and there are numerous questions on this site about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS has an article on How to upload files to the server using classic asp. ([see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299692%5b/1%5d)) once you have the file on your server then you can just add it into the db.

But remember **storing binary data in a database is usually a bad idea**

but then again if it's something super small then try it! for example I think you can just insert it into a varbinary(max) column:
example:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(YourVarbinaryColumn) 
    SELECT * FROM  
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'(name of your file to import)', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import
```

Also see: How To Display Images Stored in a BLOB Field. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173308 This technique can also be applied to other types of binary data, not just graphics.

Good Luck...